# If I @Ignore a test class in JUnit4, does @BeforeClass still run?

Tags: unit-testing, maven, junit, surefire

Quick background: I've been hunting down a Maven / Surefire test-running problem for days now, and I've narrowed it down to a small number suspect of tests.  The behavior I'm seeing is *insane*.  I start with `mvn clean test`: 250 tests run, 0 skipped.  Now, I move the suspect test into `src/test/java` and try again: 146 tests run, 0 skipped!  The output of Maven gives *no* clue that other tests aren't being run, even with the `-X` flag.

That brings me to my question: the reason I call the test 'suspect' is that the whole class is decorated with @Ignore, so I would imagine that including it in my test sources should have *no* effect at all.  Then it occurred to me -- those classes have @BeforeClass/@AfterClass methods that 
[manage a dummy Zookeeper server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422011/can-i-make-surefire-perform-expensive-setup-teardown-only-once).  It's resulted in wonky behavior before, which is why we have the tests @Ignored.

If JUnit is running the before/after code but ignoring the tests, I have no idea what might happen (but it'd probably be super bad).  Is this happening?  Is this supposed to happen?  If so, how am I *supposed* to say "for reference, here's a test that *should* work but needs fixing" when it includes @BeforeClass / @AfterClass?  Also of substantial interest: what the hell is this doing to Surefire / Maven,  that it causes unrelated tests to ***fall off the face of the Earth***?

Comment: On my machine `mvn clean test` does not run `@BeforeClass` in an `@Ignore` class. The `Skipped` counter is increasing by only one regardless of the number of @Test methods in the @Ignore class. (Maven 2.2.1, jUnit 4.9) You should attach some code and version numbers. Are you using a custom test runner?

Comment: I am not using a custom runner.  It's Maven 3.0.something, JUnit 4.8.1.

Comment: What's the version number of your surefire plugin?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you have a test with the @Ignore annotation, then it is normal behaviour for the @BeforeClass & @AfterClass to get run, whether or not all of the tests are @Ignored.

If, however, the Class has an @Ignore annotation, then the @BeforeClass & @AfterClass don't get run.

For maven, if you don't want to run any tests in a particular class, then you have to ignore them in surefire or failsafe. Add this to the maven configuration (see [Maven Surefire Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html))

```
<excludes>
 <exclude>**/FoobarTest.class</exclude>
</excludes>
```

Comment: Ugh.  So that answers the "does it work this way" question -- though, WHAT THE HELL this is so stupid, why would I want the before and after code to run for a class whose tests aren't going to run? -- but it leaves the question of how Surefire is misbehaving so strangely.  Why would some random, unrelated tests not run at all when this happens?

Comment: Is it possible that you've overlooked that "the whole class is decorated with @Ignore"?

Comment: He said that the tests were ignored, not the class. You're right that the class itself can be ignored though.

Comment: Um, but your point of view is right too. It also could mean that he annotated every method with `@Ignore`. @Coderer?

Comment: I annotated just the class with `@Ignore`.  As @Matthew points out, this means before/after will still run.  I maintain that this is a terrible, *terrible* idea.

Comment: OK just noticed the edits, now Matthew says the before/after *won't* run when the class is ignored? Maybe this varies by version of surefire / junit / maven?  I can't verify whether they run or not, but I *can* verify that my test executions go all kinds of wonky if I leave the test class ignored rather than commented-out.

Comment: Going to assume this was something buggy in my setup, as I'm having trouble reproducing.

Answer (score 8):

Environment: JDK 1.6, surefire plugin 2.9, jUnit 4.8.1, Maven 3.0, 3.0.3, 2.2.1.

I created this test class:

```
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Ignore;
import org.junit.Test;

@Ignore
public class IgnoreTest {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClass() {
        System.out.println("BEFORE CLASS");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void afterClass() {
        System.out.println("AFTER CLASS");
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("test1");
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("test2");
    }

    @Test
    public void test3() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("test3");
    }
}
```

Then `mvn clean test` print this:

```
Running hu.palacsint.stackoverflow.q7535177.IgnoreTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1, Time elapsed: 0.015 sec

Results :

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1
```

Works as you expected. If I remove the `@Ignore` and run `mvn clean test` again it prints this:

```
Running hu.palacsint.stackoverflow.q7535177.IgnoreTest
BEFORE CLASS
test2
test1
test3
AFTER CLASS
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.045 sec

Results :

Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

So, it works for me with three different Maven versions. No `@BeforeClass`/`@AfterClass` was run in `@Ignore`d classes.

There is one (maybe more) situation when `@BeforeClass`/`@AfterClass` methods could run in an `@Ignore`d test class. It's when your ignored class has a not ignored subclass:

```
import org.junit.Test;

public class IgnoreSubTest extends IgnoreTest {

    @Test
    public void test4() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("test4 subclass");
    }

}
```

Results of `mvn clean test`:

```
Running hu.palacsint.stackoverflow.q7535177.IgnoreTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1, Time elapsed: 0.047 sec
Running hu.palacsint.stackoverflow.q7535177.IgnoreSubTest
BEFORE CLASS
test4 subclass
test1
test2
test3
AFTER CLASS
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.057 sec

Results :

Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1
```

In this case the `@BeforeClass` and the `@AfterClass` methods runs because they are methods of the `IgnoreSubTest` test class.

Comment: Two things: one, note that your first execution shows "Tests run: 1" even though everything is ignored, and "Skipped: 1" even though there are three methods decorated with `@Test`.  So, Surefire (or maybe JUnit?) is already hosed there.  Two, I have way too much code to paste *everything* here but believe me when I say that `@Ignore`ing the class causes many unrelated tests to not run, while commenting out the `@BeforeClass` methods fixes the issue.  I just wish I could explain *why*.

Comment: jUnit said that "Tests run: 5 ... Skipped: 1" - It means to me that it tried to run 5 tests and 1 of the 5 has `@Ignore`. I think its correct. jUnit just works in this way. For the 2nd issue:  you should narrow your investigation to only a few tests. Save/commit your code, pick just 3-4 relevant tests and delete the others and try to reproduce a bug with this small subset of your tests.
 Then edit your question :)